# Eigenvalues of a 3x3 orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

If A is an arbitrary 3x3 orthogonal matrix with det(A)=1, then how do I show that the eigenvalues are 1, cos(x)+i sin(x), and cos(x)-i sin(X), where cos(x)=(tr(A)-1)/2.

I was thinking that maybe tr(A) equals det(A), and that gives a value for x, but I'm not sure if thats right

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your matrix is real-valued (since it would not make sense to talk about orthogonality otherwise).

Since matrix is orthogonal, it is a normal operator -> it can be diagonalized ($\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{\Gamma}^\dagger.\mathbf{\Lambda}.\mathbf{\Gamma}$). Using the fact that for real-valued matrix transpose is the same as conjugate transpose:

$$
\mathbf{M}^T=\mathbf{M}^\dagger=\mathbf{M}^{-1}=\mathbf{\Gamma}^\dagger.\mathbf{\Lambda}^{\dagger}.\mathbf{\Gamma}=\mathbf{\Gamma}^\dagger.\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}.\mathbf{\Gamma}
$$

Since $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is invertible, it follows that for matrix with eigenvalues in the diagonal:

$$
\mathbf{\Lambda}^\dagger=\left(
\begin{array}\\
\lambda_1^* & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2^*  & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3^*\\
\end{array}
\right)=
\mathbf{\Lambda}^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}\\
\lambda_1^{-1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda_2^{-1}  & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3^{-1}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So the eigenvalues of the matrix are all of the form $\lambda_s=\exp\left(i\phi_s\right),\,s=1,2,3$

Next $\mbox{det}\left[\mathbf{M}\right]=\Pi_s \exp\left(i\phi_s\right)=\exp\left(i\left[\phi_1+\phi_2+\phi_3\right]\right)=1$, so

$$
\phi_3=-\phi_1-\phi_2+2\pi n,\quad n=0,\pm1,\dots
$$

Next, if matrix is real-valued, the eigenvalues will be solutions to a cubic polynomial equation with real-valued coefficients. Therefore at least one of them will be real-valued, let it be the third one, so $\lambda_3=\pm1$. Also the other two eigenvalues will be complex conjugates of each other. So the only possibility is:

$$
\lambda_1=\exp\left(i\phi\right),\,\lambda_2=\exp\left(-i\phi\right),\,\lambda_3=1
$$

Therefore $\mbox{Tr}\left[\mathbf{M}\right]=2\cos\phi+1$

Comment: How did you get the forms of the eigenvalues and the expression for the determinant?

Comment: See edits. Just realized I used $M$ instead of $A$ for the main matrix. Determinant of a matrix is a product of its eigenvalues.

Comment: I meant, how did you get that the eigenvalues are of the form exp(i*phi)?

Comment: Any complex number can be written as $z=r\exp(i\phi)\,\quad r\ge0\, \& \,r,\phi\in\mathbb{R}$. Your determinant is not zero, so none of the eigenvalues is zero. Next solve $z^*=z^{-1}\neq 0$ and establish that $r=1$